# Trouble finding local extrema of a two variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Let $f(x,y)=4x^2+4y^2+x^3y+xy^3-xy-4$

I found out that the critical points of the function are $(0,0),(1.5,-1.5)$ and $(-1.5,1.5)$. 
$f_{xx}=8+6xy$; $f_{yy}=8+6xy$; $f_{xy}=3x^2+3y^2-1$.
$f_{xx}(1.5,-1.5)=-5.5=f_{yy}(1.5,-1.5)$ and $f_{xy}(1.5,-1.5)=12.5$. 
From here I conclude that $(1.5,-1.5)$ is a saddle point. However it's supposed to be a point of maximum. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your solution is perfectly correct -- it is a saddle point.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha shows this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=optimize+4x%5E2%2B4y%5E2%2Bx%5E3y%2Bxy%5E3-xy-4

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says it is not a saddle point

Comment: @HritRoy Wolfram Alpha [clearly states](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=saddle+points+of+4x%5E2%2B4y%5E2%2Bx%5E3y%2Bxy%5E3-xy-4) that $(1.5, -1.5)$ is a saddle point.